# Jquery Get Value of Previous Input Text Field

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to alert a previous text field's value. Here's what I've tried so far but no dice:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="foo">
</div>
<div>
    <select onchange="alert($(this).prev('input').val())">
        <option value="bar1">bar1</option>
        <option value="bar2">bar2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The `select` element does not have any siblings, so `.prev` cannot not find any element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="foo">
</div>
<div>
    <select onchange="alert($(this).parent().prev().find('input').val())">
        <option value="bar1">bar1</option>
        <option value="bar2">bar2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7tnaL/)**

You were trying to get the previous element of the select element which there isn't one of. You needed to go up to the parent div, then go to the previous div, then back down to the input.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is because it's trying to retrieve the value of the DIV element that contains the selector. .prev() searched the DOM for the element immediately preceding the element you're calling from

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="foo">
    <select onchange="alert($(this).prev().val())">
        <option value="bar1">bar1</option>
        <option value="bar2">bar2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Take a look at this jsfiddle for an example http://jsfiddle.net/2A9jJ/2/